# How to send more than one changeset for review in hg?

Tags: mercurial

After the last review 2 more commit have been done.

To send all the changeset , below command can be used.
`Hg postreview -l`

In other hand below command send one changeset alone.

```
Hg postreview -e <reviewboardid> -o <changesetid>
```

How to pass 2 changeset using hg postreview extension?

Comment: hg postreview is neither a standard command neither a Mercurial-bundled extension so you will be luckier if you ask the author of the extension. Maybe it's an extension that was developed in-house for your company?

Comment: @lothiraldan Ok. It is not in-house but it seems not a mercurial bundled extension it seems. Thanks .. Sorry for asking question in command. What is the mercurial bundled extension for review?

Comment: You can get the bug reporting link for an extension with the command: `hg debugextensions -v`.
There is no official bundled extension for review in Mercurial as there is no official way to store these review. You can send patches by mail with the patchbomb extension or use Phabricator with the phabricator one.